# How do I prevent dirty reads in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I've been trying to prevent dirty reads from occurring using different ways like starting transactions with isolation level set to READ COMMITTED. But it doesn't work. The program I'm using is based on commands from users. When they buy an item, it's supposed to check how many dollars they have using a SELECT query and then take the dollars using an UPDATE query, otherwise display an error to the user, saying they don't have enough money.

This is where dirty reads are scary. If a user started spamming the buy command, they could easily exploit it and for example spend $500 to buy two items that cost $500 each.

I made an example of the code I'm using in my project:

```
function buyItem() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connection.query("START TRANSACTION", err => {
            if (err) {
                connection.query("ROLLBACK");
                return reject(err);
            }

            connection.query("SELECT dollars FROM `my table` WHERE userID = '1670933630739' FOR UPDATE;", (err, results) => {
                if (err || !results.length) {
                    connection.query("ROLLBACK");
                    return reject(err);
                }
                const { dollars } = results[0];
                console.log(dollars);
                if (dollars < 500) {
                    connection.query("ROLLBACK");
                    return reject("not enough money");
                }
                
                const values = {
                    dollars: dollars - 500
                }
                connection.query("UPDATE `my table` SET ?", values, err => {
                    if (err) {
                        connection.query("ROLLBACK");
                        return reject(err);
                    }
                    connection.query("COMMIT");
                    resolve();
                });
            });
        });
    });
}

// The user has $1000 in the database
(async() => {
    try {
        await Promise.all([buyItem(), buyItem()]);
    } catch (ex) {
        console.error(ex);
        return;
    }
    console.log("Finished processing two user commands to buy 2 items...");
    connection.query("SELECT dollars FROM `my table` WHERE userID = '1670933630739' FOR UPDATE;", (err, results) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        const { dollars } = results[0];
        console.log(`They now have: ${dollars}`); // GETTING 500 :(
    });
})();
```

Console output:

```
1000
1000
Finished processing two user commands to buy 2 items...
They now have: 500
```

EDIT: I have provided a more realistic code that highlights the issue I'm having. Every time the user types in a command to buy an item, it'll call the `buyItem` function and calling it too quickly will result in the user paying only 500 dollars for two items. Also, I'm using InnoDB which should be supporting these locks...

Comment: Your update statement is invalid and does not seem to have an actual `SET` clause.  Please update your code that it will at least run.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It's tested and working. It takes the parameters from the values variable. It's an option in the nodejs mysql npm module

Comment: `SET ?` is not valid MySQL update syntax AFAIK.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The question mark is just a placeholder. The module replaces it with the keys and values in the values variable, that's why I passed it as a parameter. Sorry I should have mentioned it

Comment: what happen if you add  `for share nowait` on the bottom most query?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The Node.js `mysql` module does some wacky string-substitution magic when you pass a JS object as a parameter. The `?` placeholder can be replaced before the query is prepared. There's an example here: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#getting-the-id-of-an-inserted-row

Comment: Could you use a more realistic example?  Here you are just setting the user to have 500 dollars, but it sounds like you want to check first and then deduct some dollars.

Comment: Either start with `select dollars from mysterytablename where userID=? for update` or do a regular select to check the balance but also have your update be `set dollars=dollars-? where userID=? and balance>=?` and test whether it actually updated a row.  Either makes locking work for you, instead of worrying about bypassing locking.

Comment: @ysth I have modified the post to provide a more realistic code, can't get `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE;` to prevent dirty reads and making updates on uncommitted changes

Comment: Could you clarify what the `update` statement actually is? Is it `update mytable set dollars = dollars - 500` or is it `update mytable set dollars = 1000 - 500`?

Comment: What version of MySQL and what table type, please?

Comment: you should not use dollars-500 as the value of a replacement parameter; actually make your query set dollars=dollars - ?, with only the amount removed a replacement parameter.  your update is missing userID now.

Comment: please do show output of `show create table yourtablename` for the table you are testing with.  please do show (or explain exactly what you mean, if you think your existing code does show) a dirty read being allowed.

Comment: @ysth I'm firing the `buyItem` function twice each with their own SELECT statements and transactions. I expected the 2nd `SELECT` statement to only return the committed changes of the first UPDATE. This is what I'm trying to do. Make `SELECT` only return committed changes to the row.

Comment: so as far as I can tell, you are using the same connection for both.  you can't have two transactions running in the same connection, or two different sets of locks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You're updating the whole table.

Your update does not include a userID. It's updating the whole table. This *shouldn't* bypass the exclusive lock on the select for update row, but maybe it does. Either way, you don't want to update the whole table.

```
const values = {
  dollars: dollars - 500,
  userid: 1670933630739
}
```

### Avoid read then update.

You can avoid one problem by using `set dollars = dollars - 500`, rather than `set dollars = 1000 - 500`. This ensures both subtractions happen, but it does allow them to overdraw. This is good practice in general.

```
const values = [500, 1670933630739]
connection.query("UPDATE `my table` SET dollars = dollars - ? where userid = ?", values, err => {
...
```

### Do it atomically.

You can avoid the problem by doing this in a single statement.

```
update `my table`
set dollars = dollars - 500
where userID = 1670933630739 and dollars >= 500
```

The query should return the number of rows updated, so you can check if it succeeds or not.

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/7ywwGuRU).

Comment: Thank you. This is working. Is there a way at all to make SELECT only return committed changes? A way to lock a row perhaps?

Comment: @killaz I offered three solutions, which one worked? `select for update` should put an exclusive lock the rows read. Note, your final query to check their balance should not have a `for update`; I don't think it will affect the result, but just a note.

Comment: The last solution worked well for me. Thanks